# UITextFiled - textFieldShouldBeginEditing being called for every textField

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfielddelegate

I've got `UICollectionViewCell` with multiple textFields. Every single delegate is connected (once), `UITextFields` got single property (no duplicates).

Every single time I start editing `UITextField`, method `textFieldShouldBeginEditing` is being called multiple times for every `UITextField` in view.

Other views doesn't have this problem.

@Edit
Also I've tried to make a test `UICollectionViewCell` with two `UITextField`, connected delegates and `textFieldShouldBeginEditing`. And situation I've got exactly the same result - every time I select `UITextField` it fires method for every single `UITextField` in this cell.

Comment: Are you reloading the collectionview frequently?

Comment: Not at moment of click. Already checked awake/customize methods as well as cellForItemAtIndexPath. From the moment of first reload it's not being called during UITextFieldEdit.

Answer (score 1):

When textField is requested to test that it can become first responder, it asks for it's delegate via 'textFieldShouldBeginEditing' that it can become first responder or not.

Also, when you reload tableview, change it to reloading single lines may solve the problem..